# How to configure Postfix with PHP on web server to rewrite to hosting domain, not to server FQDN?

Tags: php, postfix

I might not phrase the question corectly as I obviously have limited knowledge. So hope I will explain corectly.

I setup Ubuntu + LiteSpeed web server with PHP. I intend to run a dozen of web pages for me and my friends. Control panel I installed is CyberPanel.

Now, one website, for example in Wordpress, has Feedback Form and I want all mail to go thru my own MAIL PROXY. I configured Postfix on this WEB server to use authentication user/pass on mail PROXY and it works well...
...I mean, it doesn't, because WEB server is using mail from: **hosting234@web-server.com** and of course user *hosting234* does not exist in mail system of *web-server.com* domain (which I do own).
What I want to do is to configure PHP for each web site to use own domain specific username, for example **web@user-domain.com** in FROM field.

Any idea, where and how I could acomplish this?

- either set this server-wide to be always something like **web@<customer-domain.com>**
- or set per domain on web server, maybe within Postfix or PHP

Thank you for ideas!

Comment: You're doing this at the wrong level For this to work, add an email in CyberPanel to each customer's domain, i.e. mailer@domain.com (Your second bullet without any help from PHP), then route the PHP/ Submit form button to that address using password authentication. that goes through the proxy first. Just the Traffic has to pass through, as the proxy server isn't where the e-mail ends up